# Is it possible to form adjective "morally" by deriving it from the noun "moral" (as in "of the story")?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, dictionaries

Recently I used the word *morally* as an adjective formed from the noun [moral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral). The concept I wanted to describe was that some statement is *morally* correct if you are able to agree with it intuitively but you don't necessarily have evidence or proof for it. So the statement would be a *moral* of some precise story (meaning evidence or proof).

Then it was pointed out to me that this might not be correct because *morally* is usually understood as referring to *morality*. So I looked it up in the dictionary and, indeed, I weren't able to find the meaning I wanted. So my questions are:

> 1. Is it correct to use word *morally* in the meaning I referred to above?
> 2. More generally, how do I know that words I form (e.g. by deriving adjectives from nouns) are correct? Is it enough to look in the dictionary and by not finding the word there, could I conclude that the word (or some special meaning of the word) indeed does not exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are likely to be misunderstood if you use it in that way.

I think part of the problem is that you are using (or at least defining) the noun *moral* in an odd way. To me it is not the 'proof' or 'evidence' of a story: it is the **lesson** that is embodied in the story. (Perhaps you mean that the story is 'proof' or 'evidence' of the moral - that makes more sense, but I would not think of it as either 'proof' or 'evidence', just as 'exemplification').

So I think for you the link to 'moral' is "I don't have a story to back this belief up". I am fairly confident that you will not be understood in that sense unless you give a lot of context.

Comment: Thank you Colin, this is helpful. So even the word itself might be correct, the semantic usage might not be (or at least might not be understood). I guess only experience can help me in this regard. As for the second paragraph: yes, I was talking about the story in a (quite liberal) meaning of proof/evidence.

Comment: Absolutely; this is a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, your definition

> you are able to agree with it intuitively but you don't necessarily have evidence or proof for it

pretty closely describes a jargon usage of *morally* in mathematics.  It’s a comparatively recent usage, I think, and somewhat subfield-specific.  It typically describes a statement which isn’t itself true, but succinctly captures the gist of a more complicated statement that is actually true.  E.g.:

> Giving a grading on *A* corresponds at least morally to giving a ***C***-action on spec(*A*).

> This is morally correct but technically wrong, as pointed out in Jose's answer and the comments to the question (including yours).

These and many more examples can be found at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=morally); Eugenia Cheng has [an essay](http://www.cheng.staff.shef.ac.uk/morality/) on the topic.

Comment: Oh, math... +1!

Comment: Ah, it's quite possible that this is where I got it from (either math or physics discussions). So do you think it's fine using it at least in these fields? Or do you agree with Colin that I am likely to be misunderstood?

Comment: If you are really stuck on this usage, you should italicize it initially and provide the intended meaning -- like a philosophical essay which redefines or coins words for a specific case.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is correct. Merriam-Webster lists *morally* as the adverb for of *moral*.
2. Checking a dictionary is a pretty good way to be sure. You could also search a corpus (or Google it) to see if anyone else uses the word.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I should check more dictionaries and also google for it. Will do next time.

Comment: It's grammatically correct, but its semantic usage is incorrect in this case.